# How to monitor hosts with foreman when there's only one-way traffic allowed?

Tags: dmz, foreman

I am currently setting up a PoC with foreman to monitor the configuration of some hosts. This works great.

I am wondering, how could I monitor hosts in our DMZ? Where only one way traffic is allowed (local to DMZ)? I would prefer to see the host status on the same foreman web interface.

- Is there a way to have some kind of a master/slave setup? Where the master would periodically collect slave data and display it in the web interface?
- Have any of you tried something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by reverse proxying to a Nginx server in our non-dmz environment. If you need any help on the configuration, feel free to @ me